# iPad:How to convert iPhone apps into iPad compatible?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have several iPhone apps, which i want to convert them to iPad. Is there a link where i can have a look at simple procedures about how to convert iPhons apps into iPad compatible? I already installed 3.2 SDK etc., having development environment ready.
Forgive me if it is a repeated question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really should redesign your iPhone apps for iPad (not just make them bigger), but if you just want to see what it looks without making any changes in code. Add the following to your Info.plist,

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
<integer>1</integer>
<integer>2</integer>
</array>
```

More Info: http://developer.apple.com/ipad/sdk/index.html

EDIT: see comment below

Comment: I was told that I failed at answering questions, you should use Project -> Upgrade Current Target for iPad in Xcode.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html

Comment: this way is now deprecated and even XCode will tell you to use setting within build configuration "target device family" and remove this from info.plist , you should also convert all frames to proper iPad size also ...